# What is the best way to store a user feature?

Tags: mysql, storage, normalization

A user can have one of the following jobs:

- Developer
- Designer
- Manager
- Sales
- Other

What is the best way to store that in a database? I have a column `user_job` and I can store the job in two ways:

1. As an integer (Developer=**1**, Designer=**2**, ...)
2. As the job name (**Developer**, **Designer**, ...)

   - I think the first way is faster but less clear.
   - The second way needs more storage, but the job is clear and in PHP I don't need to convert an ID to a job name.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First way. And it's not "less clear". That's why we have JOINs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is the best way to store that information in database.

```
As an integer (Developer=1, Designer=2, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Job can have any sort of information associated with it then it's usually best to have a `Job` table. I.e:

```
Job
Id   Name  Description   e.t.c.
```

And then storing as an integer pointing to the jobs id (remember and add a foreign key in the database). Apologies if that's already what you meant by 1.